# What is "a Haskell way" to transpose a graph?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Suppose I have a tree represented as a list of parents and I want to reverse the edges, obtaining a list of children for each node. For this tree - https://i.stack.imgur.com/uapqT.png - transformation would look like:

```
[0,0,0,1,1,2,5,4,4] -> [[2,1],[4,3],[5],[],[8,7],[6],[],[],[]]
```

But it's not limited to graph transposing, however. I have a few other problems that I would solve in imperative language in the following way: traverse some source data array and non-sequentially update a resulting array as I get to know something about it.

Essentially, my question is "what is Haskell's idiomatic way to solve things like this?". As I understand, I can do it in imperative way by means of mutable vectors, but isn't there some purely functional method? If not, how would I properly use mutables?

Finally, I need it to work fast, that is *O(n)* complexity, and non-standard packages are not an option for me.

Comment: What do you mean by standard package? `base` or perhaps Haskell Platform?

Comment: @AndrásKovács The Haskell Platform. I meant that I can't cabal-install anything extra, for example.

Comment: (The Haskell idiomatic way is to store a tree as a tree not an array, serialise the data using a standard traversal so it's easy to de-serealise, and let the compiler sort out the pointers instead of hacking them manually. If you want array input and array output why would you want to avoid array processing?)

Comment: @Norrius (Won't cabal install packages in your user space? Maybe that's an additional question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth to consider the pure functions in `Data.Vector` or `Data.Array` that internally use mutation, in order to be more efficient (the `accum`-s in both libraries, plus the  unfolds and `construct`-s in `vector`).

The `accum`-s are great when we don't care about intermediate states of an array during construction. They're nicely applicable for transposing graphs, although we have to provide a range for the node keys:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

import qualified Data.Array as A

type Graph = [(Int, [Int])]

transpose :: (Int, Int) -> Graph -> Graph
transpose range g =
    A.assocs $ A.accumArray (flip (:)) [] range (do {(i, ns) <- g; map (,i) ns})
```

Here we first unroll the graph into an adjacency list, but with swapped pairs of indices, and then accumulate them into an array. It's roughly as fast as a standard imperative loop over a mutable array, and it's more convenient than the ST monad.

Alternatively, we can just use `IntMap`, likely alongside the State monad, and just port our imperative algorithms as they are, and the performance will be satisfactory for most purposes.

Fortunately `IntMap` provides a lot of higher-order functions, so we're not (always) forced to program in an imperative style with it. There's an analogue for `accum`, for instance:

```
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IM

transpose :: Graph -> Graph
transpose g =
  IM.assocs $ IM.fromListWith (++) (do {(i, ns) <- g; (i,[]) : map (,[i]) ns})
```

Comment: The algorithm does not work when there are nodes with indegree 0 in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

A purely functional way would be to use a map to store the information, producing *O(n log n)* algorithm:

```
import qualified Data.IntMap as IM
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

childrenMap :: [Int] -> IM.IntMap [Int]
childrenMap xs = foldr addChild IM.empty $ zip xs [0..]
  where
    addChild :: (Int, Int) -> IM.IntMap [Int] -> IM.IntMap [Int]
    addChild (parent, child) = IM.alter (Just . (child :) . fromMaybe []) parent
```

You could also use an imperative solution and keep things pure using the [ST monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays#Mutable_arrays_in_ST_monad_.28module_Data.Array.ST.29), which is obviously *O(n)*, but the imperative code somewhat obscures the main idea:

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Data.Array
import Data.Array.MArray
import Data.Array.ST

childrenST :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
childrenST xs = elems $ runSTArray $ do
    let l = length xs
    arr <- newArray (0, l - 1) []
    let add (parent, child) =
          writeArray arr parent . (child :) =<< readArray arr parent
    forM_ (zip xs [0..]) add
    return arr
```

One drawback of this approach is that an index is out of bounds, it just fails.
Another is that you traverse the list twice. However, if you used [arrays](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays) instead of lists everywhere, this wouldn't matter.